# Does actix_web's App::register_data create a single instance or one instance per thread?

Tags: rust, actix-web

I am trying to set up a global state for my `actix_web::HttpServer`, and it seems like `register_data` is the proper API (I could be wrong).

From the [documentation](https://docs.rs/actix-web/1.0.9/actix_web/web/struct.Data.html), it is not clear to me how to create a single instance of application data shared by all `HttpServer` threads. Here is my code piece:

```
HttpServer::new(|| {
    App::new()
        .register_data(web::Data::new(Mutex::new(MyServer::new())))
        .service(web::resource("/myservice").route(web::post().to(my_service)))
        .service(web::resource("/list").to(list_service))
})
```

In the POST handler `my_service`, I update the state of `MyServer` and in the GET handler `list_service`, it will print out the state.

While `my_service` is successful in storing the state, the `list_service` only prints empty output. How do I know if `HttpServer` created a single instance of `MyServer` or not? If not, how can I ensure it creates a single instance? The [documentation](https://docs.rs/actix-web/1.0.9/actix_web/web/struct.Data.html) of `register_data` states:

> Application data does not need to be `Send` or `Sync`. Internally `Data` type uses `Arc`. if your data implements `Send` + `Sync` traits you can use `web::Data::new()` and avoid double `Arc`.

I'm confused by that. What should the user do so that `register_data` will register a single instance of the data object? Does this following line in the example from the [documentation](https://docs.rs/actix-web/1.0.9/actix_web/web/struct.Data.html) create a single instance, or one instance per thread?

```
.register_data(data.clone())
```

I'm using actix-web 1.0.9.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions) are present in the code and there's multiple missing function implementations. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify a bit. Will try to get the more complete code into it and playing the Rust Playground. Thanks.

Comment: I can stop, but without editing to meet our community standards, a post is likely to accrue more downvotes for easily-addressed reasons. The editing I do is aimed at making the question easier for people to answer **and** for other people to find in the future.

Answer (score 2):

After playing with Rust code a bit more, I understand better now. `web::Data` is an `Arc`, hence it's okay to call `data.clone()` which creates a new instance of `Arc` but still points to the single shared instance of `MyServer`. That will allow `HttpServer` threads to share a global state.

So to fix my problem, I just followed the example in the documentation, i.e, moved the data creation out of `HttpServer::new` and call `clone()` inside it:

```
    let my_data = web::Data::new(Mutex::new(MyServer::new()));
    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .register_data(my_data.clone())  // only Arc is cloned
            .service(web::resource("/myservice").route(web::post().to(my_service)))
            .service(web::resource("/list").to(list_service))    
    })
```

Comment: Btw, `actix-web::App` has two APIs to set application data: `register_data` and `data`, which is a bit confusing.