# Why does my shared actix-web state sometimes reset back to the original value?

Tags: rust, actix-web

I'm trying to implement shared state in the Actix-Web framework with `Arc` and `Mutex`. The following code compiles, but when I run it, the counter sometimes goes all the way back to 0. How do I prevent that from happening?

```
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpServer};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

// This struct represents state
struct AppState {
    app_name: String,
    counter: Arc<Mutex<i64>>,
}

fn index(data: web::Data<AppState>) -> String {
    let mut counter = data.counter.lock().unwrap();
    *counter += 1;
    format!("{}", counter)
}

pub fn main() {
    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            .hostname("hello world")
            .register_data(web::Data::new(AppState {
                app_name: String::from("Actix-web"),
                counter: Arc::new(Mutex::new(0)),
            }))
            .route("/", web::get().to(index))
    })
    .bind("127.0.0.1:8088")
    .unwrap()
    .run()
    .unwrap();
}
```

Comment: See also [Does actix_web's App::register_data create a single instance or one instance per thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59255498/155423); [Actix-Web reports “App data is not configured” when processing a file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56117273/155423)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`HttpServer::new` takes a closure which is called for each thread that runs the server. This means that multiple instances of `AppState` is created, one for each thread. Depending on which thread answers the HTTP request, you will get different instances of `data` and therefor different counter values.

To prevent this from happening, create `web::Data<AppState>` outside the closure and use a cloned reference inside the `HttpServer::new` closure.

Comment: Note that then you don’t need `Arc`: https://docs.rs/actix-web/3.1.0/actix_web/web/struct.Data.html

Comment: @roim That's probably new in actix-web 3?